# How do I build a filter to search for rooms in Active Directory in a .NET application?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, directorysearcher

I want to get all rooms in our company from active directory and for this I am using the `DirectoryEntry` and the `DirectorySearcher` classes. I need a filter that gets the right data but I don't know how I build the filter to search for the rooms.

Here is the attribute I need to filter by:

[image: msExchResourceMetaData = ResourceType:Room]

Here is my code:

```
public static DataTable GetRooms(string domaincontroller) 
{
    DataTable list = new DataTable();

    string filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=user)(|(telephoneNumber=*)(mail=*)))";

    //....

    return list; 
}
```

I need only the filter. The rest I know :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The filter you have there will give you every user with a telephone number or an email address.

If you are looking for rooms with a phone number or email address, just add in `(msExchResourceMetaData=ResourceType:Room)`:

```
string filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=user)(msExchResourceMetaData=ResourceType:Room)(|(telephoneNumber=*)(mail=*)))";
```

If you want all rooms regardless of whether they have a telephone number or email address (which I'm guessing you do), then drop the unnecessary conditions:

```
string filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=user)(msExchResourceMetaData=ResourceType:Room))";
```

Note: make sure you're wrapping everything you can in `using` blocks when working with Active Directory, or you'll wind up with memory leaks.